# How many edits of a question and of an answer will be stored by Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, edits, limits

Is there any limit beyond which the oldest edits are cleaned off automatically from Stack Overflow's database?

Comment: @Lix [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/392926/revisions) with 175 revisions

Comment: @Lix yeah I realized that after I commented. I was just in a hurry to point out the most heavily revised post. Incidentally this [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/59446/revisions) post has  328

Comment: You could conceivably make some number of edits (rate limited) under the 5 minute mark which would all be coalesced into one edit. In this case, whatever that `N` may be, you could make more physical edits than we would be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no limit to the number of edits that can be made to a post.

However, if you make too many then the post converts to community wiki and you'll no longer get any reputation changes from votes on the post.

Comment: +1: ok, I accept the answer, unless someone states for sure the contrary...:)